# migrate oracle table using chunks

Tags: oracle, chunks

I am trying to download a huge table (billions of records) from oracle DB
The base can hold a session only for a few hours (no idea why)
So my idea is to split table for many peace's and download it using dynamic sql

split query:

```
SELECT
    data_object_id,
    file_id,
    relative_fno,
    file_batch,
    subobject_name,
    MIN (start_block_id) start_block_id,
    MAX (end_block_id) end_block_id,
    SUM (blocks) blocks
      FROM
        (SELECT
           o.data_object_id,
           e.file_id,
           e.relative_fno,
           e.block_id start_block_id,
           e.block_id + e.blocks - 1 end_block_id,
           e.blocks,
           CEIL (SUM(e.blocks) OVER (PARTITION BY o.data_object_id, e.file_id ORDER BY e.block_id ASC) /
             (SUM (e.blocks)OVER (PARTITION BY o.data_object_id,e.file_id) / 1)) file_batch
        FROM
          dba_extents e,
          dba_objects o,
          dba_tab_subpartitions tsp
        WHERE
          o.owner = :owner
          AND o.object_name = :object_name
          AND e.owner = :owner
          AND e.segment_name = :object_name
          AND o.owner = e.owner
          AND o.object_name = e.segment_name
          AND (o.subobject_name = e.partition_name
            OR (o.subobject_name IS NULL
              AND e.partition_name IS NULL))
          AND o.owner = tsp.table_owner(+)
          AND o.object_name = tsp.table_name(+)
          AND o.subobject_name = tsp.subpartition_name(+))
  GROUP BY
    data_object_id,
    file_id,
    relative_fno,
    file_batch
  ORDER BY
    data_object_id,
    file_id,
    relative_fno,
    file_batch;
```

it splits usual table, but it doesn't work with partition or subpartition tables (when I try to download it has more or less lines than it is in DB)

the queries for download I used:

```
SELECT /*+ NO_INDEX(t) */ COLUMN_NAMES,'63_17' data_chunk_id
 FROM OWNER.OBJECT_NAME t
 WHERE ((rowid >= dbms_rowid.rowid_create(1, 846313, 63, 3057792, 0) 
   AND rowid <= dbms_rowid.rowid_create(1, 846313, 63, 4056447, 32767)));
```

Comment: Can you use expdp tool instead? It could be easier to just create a view with the result of your table and use expdp to export the data.

Comment: Try parallelizing your extract. For example, fork 10 async threads, each one makes a connection and pulls 1/10th of the data using a MOD function on a suitable column (PKs work well).  So, thread 1 would pull *WHERE MOD(pkcol,10)+1 = 1* and thread 2 would pull *WHERE MOD(pkcol,10)+1 = 2*, etc.. then combine the ten results into one after they are all done.

Answer (score 0):

Check out DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE. Even if you don't use it "completely", ie, to run the extract, you can use the DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID routine to generate a list of rowid ranges that you can then use to run your rowid range queries that you've already written.